# Map angular head http method response

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

How can I retrieve the response header from a request with head http method?

```
getCount(): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.head(`${this.baseUrl}`)
      .pipe(
        map((event: any) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            return +event.headers.get('header-name');
          }
          return 0;
        }),
      );
  }
```

event is always null

**Solution**

```
getCount(): Observable<number> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}`;
    return this.http.head(url, {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(
        map((event: any) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            return +event.headers.get('header-name');
          }
          return 0;
        }),
      );
  }
```

Comment: What is the value of `options`? Have you read https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response?

Comment: You can ignore the options. That was a typo.

Comment: No, we can't. Since, if you read the documentation that I linked to, you precisely need to pass a specific option to be able to read the response. Click the link and read.

Comment: I was wondering if I can use pipe and map instead of subscribe

Comment: If you don't subscribe, you never send any request, so the mapping function will never be executed. That is also explained in the http guide that I linked to. Read it.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet. that helped.

Comment: @JB Nizet I could only vote up your comment but thank  you, that solved my problem ( yours  should have been the accepted answer, not sure if anyone can fix that ? ) .